# Is Interface as labels a bad practice in java OO?

Tags: java, interface, label

During the parsing of certain xml files, I come across a situation that I have to use interface as labels to identify that certain tags belong to certain category, for example, I created a **Tag** interface to identify that these classes are used to represent xml tags, and **ContainableTag** to point out that certain tags can be one of the children tags of some tags.

Then I stumble into this page: [http://xahlee.org/java-a-day/interface.html](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/interface.html) (Please look for the "*Interface as Labels*" session.). It says:

> The gist of the problem is that it is
> a piece of mathematical irrelevance in
> the language. As a labeling mechanism
> in a language, for the possible
> benefit from the software engineering
> perspective, then it should not be
> designed as part of the Class
> Interface, since the concept of
> labeling, and concept of programing
> interface, are semantically disparate.

So is interface as labels necessarily a bad practice? As a java programmer, do we have some other alternatives?

Comment: You should point out the existing queries on this topic at SO. They also contain a lot of references. Interesting article you dug out, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interfaces as markers have largely been replaces by the annotation mechanism in Java 5 or later.  They allow you to add arbitrary meta-data.  If your interfaces are empty and are only serving to act as class markers, then you should be using annotations instead.

Comment: I never look into the usages of annotations, although I use it in certain frameworks. Thank you. I will google for tutorials.

Could you also pass me some links of annotation tutorial if you happen to have some at hand?

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html

The biggest gotcha in using annotations is that you need to annotate your annotations with a retention of 'runtime' if you want to use them at runtime.  By default they're discarded by the compiler.

Comment: Another gotcha with annotations is that they are not inherited by default by the subclasses. You need to specify @Inherited (http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) on the annotation to achieve that

Answer (score 8):

While annotations may provide an alternative for what marker interfaces accomplish, they are only available in Java, and do not integrate well with IDEs: I also use marker interfaces to tag related concepts in my project, and I can then use the type hierarchy browser to find all members (I guess this will be eventually supported by major IDEs for annotations soon).

As for the article you mention, I do not see the point in arguing that if a class syntactically/structurally "fulfills" an interface, that interface may/should be applied automatically to the class ("Any class can declare it [RandomAccess] as a interface..."). That's backwards thinking, in my opinion.

I would argue that the places, where such a marker interface is used in an `instanceof' statement, use inverted logic, but as long as you are stuck within a language without multiple inheritance, aspects and annotations, I see no better way to accomplish this without stepping out of the base language.

Also note that this dead-beat argument about an empty interface always being applicable could also be applied to annotations.

Answer (score 6):

Annotations are not necessarily what you want. Tagging interfaces are a way of working a property of a type into the type itself. For example, if you're about to start writing code looking like this:

```
@interface ContainableTag{}

@ContainableTag public class Foo {}

// ... elsewhere...

/**
 * Adds obj as a child element.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if obj is not tagged with 
 *         the ContainableTag annotation.
 */
public void addElement(Object obj){
    if (!obj.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(ContainableTag.class))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("obj is not a ContainableTag");
    // add the containable tag as an element
}
```

Then consider if you really don't think this looks better:

```
interface ContainableTag {}

public class Foo implements ContainableTag {}

// ... elsewhere...

public void addElement(ContainableTag ct){
    // add the containable tag as an element
}
```

Sure, the tagging interface does not provide any information about what behavior the type itself provides, but it *does* allow other types to enforce this non-behavioral property. I certainly would have been spared a lot of annoying bugs if `ObjectOutputStream` had a `writeObject(Serializable)` method rather than `writeObject(Object)`.

**Edit:** I have [not insignificant support](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA179#v=onepage&q=&f=false) here.

Comment: Haha.. my "effective java" is too old to have this article. Thank you.