# What is the purpose for using an empty interface that extends another in Java?

Tags: java, interface, guice

I just begin to maintain a Java MVC project which use Java Guice Framework.

In almost the entire code, first developers passed as parameter an empty model interface  **extending** another interface.

Here's the first Interface:

```
public interface FooModel extends ModelInterface {

}
```

And the other interface:

```
 public interface ModelInterface {
        public void addListener(FooListener fooListener);
        void setFoo(boolean blop);
        boolean isFoo();
    }
```

That does not make any sense for me.

Is there a good reason/pattern use empty interface, in Java? Maybe for Guice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436674/is-interface-as-labels-a-bad-practice-in-java-oo/1437231#1437231) is a good motivation for "marker interfaces". They are especially useful in aspect-oriented programming where they give you a point to attach to (and I guess Guice is just such a framework).

Answer (score 3):

Only reason i know to use an empty interface would be as a marker interface. There are some examples like  java.lang.Cloneable or Serializable.

Answer (score 2):

It could be used to mark a class for a specific use.

Example: [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx)